# Retry to connect to server callback on failure in Angular 2

Tags: angular, api, typescript, callback

In my API parent class I'm implementing all the methods needed to communicate with the server.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(protected http: Http,
              protected snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
  }

  get<T>(resourceUrl: string, queryOptions?: { [key: string]: any; }): Observable<T> {
    this.progressBarService.show();

    const endpoint = resourceUrl + this.createQueryString(queryOptions);

    const callback = () =>  { return this.get<T>(resourceUrl, queryOptions); };

    return this.http.get(endpoint)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch((err: Response, caught: Observable<T>) => {
        return this.catchError(err, this.snackBar, callback);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.progressBarService.hide();
      });
  }

  protected catchError(error: Response | any, snackBar: MdSnackBar, callback: Function) {
    if (!environment.production) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    const errorMsg = 'Error while connecting the server.';

    const snackBarRef = snackBar.open(errorMsg, 'Retry', {duration: 3000});

    snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
      callback();
    });

    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
  }
}
```

If an error happens I'm using the `catchError()` function to show a `snackBar` to the user with a static message. If the user click on "Retry" button, I'm using the callback function to retry to connect. Using the `callback()` in the `catchError` function nothing happen. I'm sure the `callback` is called because I've even try to put some `console.log()` inside it and I can see the messages on the console.

Comment: I think your problem is that the first call returns an observable which is (presumably) subscribed to.  The second call is also returning an observable but probably no one is subscribing to it.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this? Maybe adding a `share()` ?

Comment: Sorry, too tired to provide a full answer tonight.  One approach that jumps to mind would be to create a subject.  Each time you call get then subscribe to it (inside of the `get<T>` method) and publish to the subject.  Then return the subject.

Comment: an example would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
  get<T>(resourceUrl: string, queryOptions?: { [key: string]: any; }, subject: Subject<T> = null): Observable<T> {
    this.progressBarService.show();

    const endpoint = resourceUrl + this.createQueryString(queryOptions);

    subject = subject || new Subject<T>();

    const callback = () =>  { return this.get<T>(resourceUrl, queryOptions, subject); };

    let obs = this.http.get(endpoint)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch((err: Response, caught: Observable<T>) => {
        return this.catchError(err, this.snackBar, callback);
      });

    obs.subscribe(res => {
      this.progressBarService.hide();
      subject.next(res);
      subject.complete();
    });

    return subject;
  }
```

The only thing I would change is, if the user somehow decided not to reissue the request, you should probably call `subject.error()` to clean up the subject and notify any listeners that they will never be getting an answer.